# Make another app's windows borderless

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow

Is there any way to remove the window border (i.e., make the [style `NSBorderlessWindowMask`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Tasks/SettingWindowAppearance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000232-135704)) for a window that belongs to another application?

Comment: Window Border? What are you talking about? Mac OS X apps *don't have* a window border.

Comment: Can you be more specific please

Comment: @Moshe Apple use the term borderless for windows without the peripheral elements.

Comment: @Bavarious - What do you mean?

Comment: @Moshe In Cocoa, for example, a titlebar is considered a peripheral element. If a window is borderless, the titlebar isn’t shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those windows don't belong to your application. Your only hope is hackery.

Look into something like [SIMBL](http://www.culater.net/software/SIMBL/SIMBL.php) to inject code into the other applications. There's also [ApplicationEnhancer](http://unsanity.com/haxies/ape).

Good luck - screw-ups here can destablize others' apps or the entire system. Also, I highly doubt Apple will let you play in their App Store if your app does this.

Comment: Apple definitely wouldn't permit that.

Comment: I've been experimenting with not speaking in certainties about the things I hope will change. Maybe the Universe (or just Apple) is listening and will start to agree. ;-)